# Where is the flaw in this argument with $p$-adic extensions?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, model-theory, p-adic-numbers

I cannot find what I am missing in the following computation. Let $K=\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/{(p-1)p^{\infty}}})$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^{\infty}})$, where $\zeta_{p^n}$ is a primitive $p^n$-th root of unity. I think I have computed that $\mathcal{O}_K/p\cong \mathcal{O}_L/p\cong \mathbb{F}_p[t^{1/p^{\infty}}]/t^{p-1}:=R$, which is perfect (I can provide more details for this computation if needed). We should then have that for the $p$-adic completions $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}_p[p^{1/{(p-1)p^{\infty}}}]}\cong \widehat{\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_{p^{\infty}}]}\cong W(R)$ since there is a unique strict $p$-ring having a given perfect ring $R$ of characteristic $p$ as its residue ring (Theorem 5, pg.39 Local Fields Serre). However, I know this cannot be true. Maybe there is an easier way to see it but here is an argument: By Corollary 5.10 in [Kuhlmann - The algebra and model theory of tame valued fields](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0194), we get that $L$ is relatively algebraically closed in its completion. In particular, if the above isomorphism is true, this would give us that $p^{1/p}\in L$. But since $L/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is abelian, this would imply that $\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p})$ is Galois, which is not true. 
p.s. This is related to a question that I posted on mathstack: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3662451/what-is-wrong-with-this-application-of-ax-kochen

Comment: For a ramified extension $\mathbf Z_p \subseteq \mathcal O_K$, the ring $\mathcal O_K/p$ is _never_ perfect, because an element $x$ with valuation $0 < v(x) < v(p)$ satisfies $x^{p^r} = 0$ in $\mathcal O_K/p$ for $r \gg 0$, but $x$ is not zero in $\mathcal O_K/p$.

Comment: Perfect here means that the Frobenius is surjective, not bijective.

Comment: Edit: But you might be right; in Serre's book pg.39 he defines a ring to be perfect if the Frobenius is actually an automorphism. So probably the theorem that I used doesn't apply.

Comment: As far as I know, the usual definition of perfect ring is that the Frobenius is an isomorphism, but I agree that the wording in Serre is confusing.

Comment: A characteristic $p$ ring in which Frobenius is merely surjective is apparently sometimes called *semiperfect*. (also, I believe the word "perfect" also meant "bijective" in the lecture we were attending this week :) )

Comment: I think that both completions $\hat{L}$ and $\hat{K}$ are isomorphic, and are both perfectoid fields which are _untilts_ of the same perfectoid field $\mathbb{F}_p((t))/t^{p-1}$. In particular, they are isomorphic. As for Kuhlmann, observe that $L^c/L$ is not algebraic, hence not separable. For tilts/unitlts/perfectoid, you can certainly look at Scholze's IHES paper, or at lectures 2 and 3 by Lurie here https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/205.html

Comment: @Wojowu Hi Wojtek, I think that in that context perfect really meant semiperfect; what we were calling perfect $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebras were things like $A/pA$ for strict $p$-rings $A$(see definition 3.3.1 https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gulotta/hodge_notes.pdf). These are never perfect in the bijective sense for ramified $A$ as R. van Dobben de Bruyn pointed out. Right?

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo Hi Fillippo, thanks for your answer.The fact that they are untilts of the same perfectoid field does certainly not imply they are isomorphic; the completions of $\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p^{\infty}})$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^{\infty}})$ are standard examples of non-isomorphic fields having the same tilt up to isomorphism.

Comment: @KostasKartas To be honest, I am still not 100% sure about that. I know that Kedlaya in [his article](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1186/s40687-015-0031-z.pdf) requires perfect algebras to have bijective Frobenius, and the frequent uses of $x^{p^{-n}}$ (which otherwise would not be well-defined) make me thing our lectures demands that too. I agree bijectivity fails for $A/pA$ for $A$ ramified, but it doesn't seem to me we ever need to use results about perfect algebras for them (e.g. we never form $W(A/pA)$, only $W(\mathcal O_K)$ when $K$ has characteristic $p$).

Comment: @Wojowu It seems you are right, sorry for misleading you with my comment in the chat of the lecture!